# ASP.NET Web API with Facebook auth without OWIN

Tags: facebook, api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm developing an ASP.NET Web API. The authentication used in this API does not use OWIN, and I need to make a method that authenticates a user by using their Facebook account.

I only find examples on how to do this by using OWIN and OAuth. Is there another way to do this?

Can someone post some link or explanation about this case?

Thanks in advance!